# Did the ancients really think mangoes were garlic like?

Tags: meaning

Flipping through Endymion Wilkinson's *Chinese History: A New Manual* I came across the following excerpt:

> 36 Food & Drink
> 36.7 Ming-Qing
> Mangoes: fansuan 番蒜, mangguo 芒果 (Malay mangga?)

番蒜 is a very funny word to call mangoes. 番蒜 is basically made up of two parts:

- 番 = foreign
- 蒜 = garlic

Did the ancients really think mangos were garlic like? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually the 蒜 is evidence of a *substrate influence* from an Austroasiatic language (ancestor of Vietnamese *xoài* or Khmer *ស្វាយ [svaay]*) in this context. Indeed, this lexeme actually does have its own Chinese character, [**檨**](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AA%A8), with Mandarin pronunciation *shē* (ㄕㄜ).

It is the Hakka and Min varieties which use this [檨 lexeme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AA%A8#Chinese):

- Taiwanese Min Nan: soāiⁿ (Peh-oe-ji), [suāinn](https://www.moedict.tw/%27%E6%AA%A8) (Tai-lo), ㄙㄨㆮ˫ (Zhuyin)
- Fuzhounese Min Dong: [suông](https://www.ydict.net/feng/p291_23) (Bang-ua-ce)
- Taiwanese Hakka: sôn (Phak-fa-sü)

In many of these varieties, the pronunications of [蒜](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%92%9C) are very close:

- Taiwanese Min Nan: soàn (Peh-oe-ji)
- Fuzhounese Min Dong: sáung (Bang-ua-ce)
- Taiwanese Hakka: son (Phak-fa-sü)

Hence the substitution of 蒜 was motivated by phonetic similarity (假借) with the lack of "availability" of this 檨 character.

In many of these, the collocation 番檨, preferred in Min Dong and certain varieties of Hakka, may help distinguish it from just 蒜. Or it may just be that mangoes came a bit later to the northeastern Fujian area than the southern area.

Comment: That seems like a much more reasonable explanation than, "western garlic."

Comment: For those who are interested, the [*Nôm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%E1%BB%AF_N%C3%B4m) character for Vietnamese **xoài** is  ([U+234B1](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=234b1), [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_languages#Ideographic_Description_Sequences): ⿰木吹).